# Using JUnit and TestNG together

Tags: java, testing, junit, testng

Do you think it's a good idea to use JUnit and TestNG together in one project? I need some features from TestNG, but I also need JUnit specific extensions, like DbUnit and XmlUnit.

And if I use them together, do you think I should put both test package trees in the same "test" folder in my Eclipse project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBUnit works fine with TestNG but nevertheless, you can run both JUnit 3 and TestNG tests at the same time: all you need to do is to put your JUnit 3 classes in a tag

```
<test junit="true">
</test>
```

and all your other TestNG classes in a regular:

```
<test>
</test>
```

Look for the string "junit" in [the documentation](http://testng.org) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use DBUnit with TestNG? As far as I can tell, it doesn't have anything specific to TestNG. Just have to define the import in TestNG's before test, and afterTest.

I would be surprised if XMLUnit couldn't be used in a similar matter.